# How can I simplify this array filter expression?

Tags: swift

I need to find all objects, which contains in first and second arrays. I have this code, which works fine:

```
let items = catalog.items.filter({ (item) -> Bool in
                        orderItems.contains { $0.id == item.id }
                    })
```

But I want to reduce that it will look like:

```
catalog.items.filter{items.contains{ $0.id == first.id }}
```

where first.id - is element from catalog.items. How can I do it?))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Single line solution:

```
catalog.items.filter { item in orderItems.contains { $0.id == item.id }}
```